# Accessing sub-objects with the property '$' in PHP

Tags: php, object

I've JSON decoded a result from the CNET API and got the following (after var_dump()):

```
object(stdClass)#4 (35) { 
    ["Summary"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (1) { 
        ["$"]=> string(89) "Record keystrokes, visited web sites, and screenshots of all PC
activity in stealth mode."
    }
    ["Requirements"]=> object(stdClass)#6 (0) {}
    ["CNETContentIds"]=> object(stdClass)#7 (0) { } 
    ["CleverBridgeUrl"]=> object(stdClass)#8 (0) { } 
    ["BuyNowUrl"]=> object(stdClass)#9 (1) {
        ["@type"]=> string(0) "" 
    }
    ...
```

How do I access that 89-character string in the variable named "$"?

I've tried this:

```
$object->Summary->$
```

But my editor gave me an error.

I know, from trial and error that you can just string '->'s together to access nested objects, but it's so strange that a member is named $?

Even escaping the $ doesn't work:

```
$object->Summary->\$
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access non-standard property names with brackets `{}`:

```
$object->Summary->{'$'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
$object->Summary->{'$'}
```

Or even

```
$object->{'Summary'}->{'$'}
```